# Why is my read data MCP23017 not working

Tags: gpio, python

I'm trying to add a button to my `MCP23017` board. But my code is not working. What am i doing wrong?

```
import smbus
import sys
import getopt
import time 
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
bus.write_byte_data(0x20,0x00,0xff) # input
bus.write_byte_data(0x20,0x01,0xff) # input
address = 0x20 # I2C address of MCP23017

# Handle the command line arguments
def main():
  while True:
    print(bus.read_byte_data(address, 0x12))
    time.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

print is 0, even if i press the button

Comment: Do you have a schematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a schematic, as @gnibbler said, I would guess that it is a circuit issue.  Try setting up your circuit as if it were voltage divider, with a pullup resistor to 3.3v.  The size isn't that important for a proof of concept, but I would say ~1k is what I would shoot for.  See the schematic below for a simple explanation.

[image]

Comment: @user6827 Any time!  Throw an up vote at gnibblers comment, he deserves credit as well.